# How to expand a chardef token to a character?

Tags: tex-core, conditionals, expansion

This is perhaps a basic question, but I am quite confused now.

> How should I expand a box register to a character?
>
> For example, after `\newbox\foo`, suppose `\number\foo` equals 26, how should I compare `\foo` as a character to another character, like `\if\foo b`?

I am trying to test the equality of `\foo` after a `\newbox` command with the character it represents, just to see if I know how to work with this, but if I type (assume `\number\foo` gives 26),

```
\newbox\foo
\if\foo\char26 yes\else no\fi
```

I get `26 yes`.

So I try to expand as follows.

```
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter%
\if\expandafter\expandafter\foo\char26 yes\else no\fi
```

Then I still get `26 yes`, as (this took me some time to figure out) `\char` happens at the final stage of processing (the execution processor, to quote "TeX by Topic").

Further, I think maybe using `\uccode` can solve the problem, so I tried:

```
\uccode\lq b=26
\uppercase{\if\foo b yes\else no\fi}
```

Then I get `NO æ`. Maybe I have to somehow extract the character from `\foo`?

And I suddenly realize that `\foo` is equivalent with `\char26`.

---

Sorry if this question appears messy; I am not very clear about the macro structures of TeX yet. Any help or reference will be sincerely appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: `\ifnum\number\foo=26 yes\else no\fi`?

Comment: 'You can't': boxes contain _typesetting_ instructions, not characters in a sense that TeX will allow a comparison. (Yes, often the content is largely made up of character slots that look much like text, but that's not the same thing.) Can you specify what you are actually trying to achieve in a wider sense?

Comment: @Manuel Thanks a lot! Why I forgot I can test equality on numbers! If you post an answer, I shall accept that. :)

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks for the information. I just found that after a `\newbox` command, it can be used as a number, so I thought maybe I can treat it as a character with that character code, but it turns out that, with `\char` I don't know how. :(

Comment: How can this be useful? The number that's allocated to the new box register can change as soon as you load another package in your preamble. You should *never* use the allocated number for any reason whatsoever, because it's essentially random.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the reply. I am only trying to experiment some properties of the conditionals and the number allocated to the registers. :)

Comment: note that the question title is misleading. after `\newbox\foo` then `\foo` is not a box regiseter it is just a chardef token defined by `\chardef\foo=26` (or whatever number)  `\foo` itself is unrelated to any box register. `\box\foo` refers to a box register but only because `\foo` is 26 and `\box26` accesses a box register.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for pointing this out. I have corrected the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what are you exactly trying to achieve, and this seems weird, but you can test with `\ifnum`

```
\ifnum\number\foo=26 yes\else no\fi
```

Comment: May be you can just write `\ifnum\foo=26 yes\else no\fi` but I haven't tested.

Comment: Just tested; it works, thanks. :D Also I explain a little in the reply to Joseph Wright. :)

Comment: Doesn't `\char\number\foo` work? Or `\char\foo`? Still, I don't get why would you try to do that, you can may be explain a real use case in your question?

Comment: I think `\foo` just outputs that character already? Eh, I don't have any specific use in mind, just trying to know how the conditionals work in different cases, or how they interact with other commands, and familiarizing myself with the tex commands.

Comment: You are supposed to use `\box\foo` or `\copy\foo` to get what's in the box. The fact that `\foo` outputs a character is just a side effect. In any case, it doesn't expand to that character, it ouputs it. So you can't use `\foo` in `\if` or `\ifx`. May be with LuaTeX or XeLaTeX you can do `\Uchar\foo` and it will actually expand to the character.

Comment: There are a few good questions in this site about conditionals, about expansion, about boxes, etc. You can read them and learn more than I just cryptically said in my comment (and I might be even wrong).

Comment: Surely I shall read them. :-D

Comment: `\number` is redundant

Comment: @egreg Yes, it was answered in the comments but I didn't edit the question. Your answer seems more complete anyways :)

Answer (score 8):

This is like defining a global variable in a high level programming language and trying to use the memory register address of that variable in the same program. This will obviously not work.

Consider the simple example (in plain TeX)

```
%\input manmac
\newbox\foo

\foo
\bye
```

This will print a dotless i, because it turns out that the box register allocated is number 16 and the `cmr10` font has that character in slot 16.

Now uncomment the first line and you will get a breve accent, because it turns out that the box register allocated is number 20. Why is that? Simple: `manmac.tex` contains four `\newbox` declarations.

You clearly see that you can't foresee what number the box register will correspond to, but this is of no consequence for your programs, *provided you never refer to the number directly*, but only with its symbolic name `\foo`.

The fact that `\newbox\foo` internally does `\chardef\foo=<number>` should never be exploited in programs. It's just *implementation* and uses the property that a `\chardef` token can be used in the context of a number.

Using `\foo` in any other context than for boxes is ***wrong***: your output will be unpredictable, as the previous example shows.

---

Let's turn to a different point of view. Suppose you do

```
\chardef\foo=26
```

This is a perfectly legal instruction and `plain.tex` has lots of similar ones, for instance

```
\chardef\#=`#
```

(where `` `# `` refers to the ASCII code of the `#` character). Now `\foo` can be used to print the glyph occupying slot 26 in the current font. If the current font is `cmr10`, you get ‘æ’; if the current font is `ecrm1000`, you get ‘ȷ’ (dotless j).

You see that `\foo` does not refer to a *character* (considered as an abstract entity), but just to a slot: it's simply an instruction

> print the glyph sitting at slot 26 in the current font

There are some conventions, of course; for instance slot 98 will contain a ‘b’ in most font; but if the current font is `tcrm1000` you would get ‘ ⁀’ (a tie accent).

Even `\#` would have quite unpredictable results if used with some fonts: with `wasy10` you get ‘○’ (a white circle).

Conclusion: comparing a `\chardef` token with a character makes no sense.